# Eclipse CDT: Attach to local Application missing

Tags: debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) with Cygwin to build and debug a DLL.
This DLL is loaded by a third party application that I want to attach my GDB to for debugging.
As I've heard this can be done by creating a Debug Configuration named "Attach to local Application". I only have "Attach to Application".

[image]
[image]

And it doesn't ask me for a process ID to attach to. When I start debugging it just shows this error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
(If you wonder why I'm using an old gdb version: Newer versions won't run on my PC, don't know why. It's a Win10 64bit system with newest updates).